# I can't open the NEW TAB in google Chrome Using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

this is my line to open the new tab

```
 driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"t");
```

Comment: I would *not* recommend using tabs.  They aren't supported in selenium.  It will work, but trying to run commands on different tabs isn't a good way to have multiple processes.

Comment: The above code works only in FF not in Chrome. For Chrome you can use JS

Answer (score 5):

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open();");
```

This JavaScript code opens a new tab for the Chrome browser.

Answer (score 4):

Use Actions class in WebDriver to do this. Below is a sample code:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.navigate().to("<URL>");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body"));
Actions actionOpenLinkInNewTab = new Actions(driver);
actionOpenLinkInNewTab.moveToElement(element).keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(element).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

this following code works for me in selenium 3 and chrome 58.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://yahoo.com");  
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open()");
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
driver.get("http://google.com");
```

Comment: Yes, the above code is worked well both in Chrome and FF

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    Actions newTab = new Actions(webDriver);
    newTab.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t").perform();
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works in `Firefoxdriver` but not in `Chromedriver`.
One solution is that you can open any `link` on current page into new tab.
Following is the `Python` code for it.

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
home_link = driver.find_element_by_class_name("logo")
actions.move_to_element(home_link)
actions.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+ Keys.SHIFT)
actions.click(home_link)
actions.perform()
```