# Is there an equivalent selenium python webdriver command for the selenium IDE command 'openWindow'?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-ide

We have a selenium IDE script we're converting to python webdriver.  The following command did not convert:

```
[openWindow | http://mywebsite.com/index.php | window1]]
```

I've searched for the equivalent webdriver command for openWindow, but I haven't found anything.  Can someone tell me what the best way is to deal with this command in webdriver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid there is **no direct alternative** in the webdriver API, no way to work with browser tabs reliably (except switching between open tabs through [`switch_to.window()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to_window)). Even to open a tab, keyboard shortcuts is the only way, see:

- [How to open a new tab using Selenium WebDriver with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver)
- [I can't open the NEW TAB in google Chrome Using selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174329/i-cant-open-the-new-tab-in-google-chrome-using-selenium)
- [switch tabs using Selenium WebDriver with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729265/switch-tabs-using-selenium-webdriver)

Just instantiate a new driver if you need to open a "new window" and use `driver.get()` to navigate to a URL.

Comment: Thanks again alecxe.  I just instantiated a new driver.